# @Inject in guice module

Tags: guice

Do we need @Inject over provides___ method in the module class?
Eg.

```
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @Inject
    A provideA(ExampleClass1<B> example1, ExampleClass2 example2) {
        return new A(example1, example2);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Inject
    B provideB(A a) {
        return new B(new C(a));
    }
```

In this example, do I need @Inject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `@Provides` methods do not need the `@Inject` annotation. Arguments to a `@Provides` method are already injected automatically.